# Browser tooltip not working in d3.js bar chart

Tags: browser, d3.js, tooltip

when i add a browser tooltip using append(title) function it shows undefined is not an function what is the reason. if i remove that it works fine.y source code is below. But when i saw some examples in net,they did the same one,but for me it is not working.Am i missed anything?

```
 dataset = [{"label":"Abc", "value":140}, 
 {"label":"Bbc", "value":200}, 
            {"label":"Def", "value":90}, 
            {"label":"Ghi", "value":100}, 
            {"label":"jkl", "value":210}, 
            {"label":"Mno", "value":40}, 
            {"label":"Pqr", "value":170}]
            ;


var h = 400,
    w = 700;

// create svg element
var chart = d3.select('body')
              .append('svg') // parent svg element will contain the chart
              .attr('width', w)
              .attr('height', h);     

var barwidth = w / dataset.length;
var spacing =1;
var chartPadding = 50;
var chartBottom = h - chartPadding; // 350
var chartRight = w - chartPadding; // 750


   //CHART CODE

          chart.selectAll('rect')
         .data(dataset)
         .enter()        
         .append('rect') 

        .transition().duration(1000)
         .attr(
             'x', function(d) {
                 return xScale(d.label); 
                 // instead of return i * barwidth
             })
             .attr('y', function(d) {
                 return yScale(d.value);
                 // instead of return h - d.value
             })
            .attr( 'width', xScale.rangeBand())
            // gives bar width with space calculation built in
            // instead of barwidth - spacing
             .attr('height', function(d) {
                 return chartBottom-yScale(d.value);
                // instead of return d.value
             })
             .attr('fill', 'orange');




//CHART CODE OVER







var y_axis = chart.append('g')
            .attr('class','axis')
            .attr('transform','translate(' + chartPadding + ',0)');

yAxis(y_axis);
```

Comment: You aren't appending any `title` elements in your code.

Comment: yes.. but i append that append("title").text(function(d){return d.value;}); it shows undefined is not an function in the debugger window

Comment: Where do you put that code?

Comment: after that attr("fill",orange).append("title").text("Hai");

Comment: My js fiddle is below.. Here i added the append function   http://jsfiddle.net/Sfz97/

Comment: You can't append to a transition, append to the selection: http://jsfiddle.net/Sfz97/1/

Comment: Oh! thats fine Thanks Lars...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that you cannot perform the

```
.append("svg:title")
.text("hai");
```

after the transition has started with

```
.transition()
.duration(1000)
```

The reason is that the object returned by the chained `.transition()` operation does not have the method .append(). What you want to do instead is to save the object where you later want to do a transition to a variable. Then perform the `.append()`, then to the transition.

See this Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/willeeklund/Sfz97/6/

Note that I also first set values to the `y` and `height` values of the bars, to make the transition/animation prettier.

Best of luck!
/Wille

Comment: fine wille,, thanks for ur suggestion.. And i facing new problem would u help me.. see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623959/how-to-fill-half-of-the-rectangle-with-color-in-d3-js